# Is it possible to restrict Generic to certain types?

Tags: typescript, types

Is it possible to restrict Generic type to `string | number` only?

Here is the example of the function I'm trying to type (each element of the array needs to be mapped to the key on the return object):

```
([foo, bar]) => ({ [foo]: 1, [bar]: 2 })
```

I tried to use a type with Generic but it complains about Generic not being `string | number | symbol`

```
type GetContext = <T>([T]) => Record<T, any>;
```

Is it possible restricting it only to types accepted by an object key?

If not, is there any other way of mapping function argument to the object key?

Comment: Why is this generic at all? Shouldn't the signature just be `(args: [(string | number), (string | number)]) => Record<string | number, any>`?

Comment: I want the key of the object to be exactly the same value as inside passed array. 
`['foo'] => {foo: any}`

Comment: You can saysay `<T extends string | number>` but it doesn't guarantee you'll know what the key name is: [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA4hwGED2A7YEAewoF4oB4AVKTdFAEwGcpLgAnASxQHMoAfKFAVwFsAjCHQB8ACgwAuKAG1CAXQCUuIVABKEAMZI65IgBooAQxQghAbgBQ5DQBsDdaJpS0oAM0lxEqdFgvnr8VyQkSVpGFlwoACIXIMiLR2dUaDwXESkYpAVTKByAely1TW18UKZmfSMTcwTsYAB3JAjUqUi+O0isqHzCrR1W9orjIXMgA)